# Exit Windows Form Application after x minutes of inactivity of windows c#

Tags: c#, winforms, exit

I want my application to close itself after x minutes of Windows inactivity, not based on the inactivity of my own application.
I know I should watch keyboard and mouse events. But I don't know how. Should I use Import dll?
My question isn't unique and It's been asked here:[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32758362/close-c-sharp-app-after-10-minutes-of-inactivity#), But I'm not convinced.
Any answer would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I wanted my application to close when no body is working with computer for instance in 2 minutes. 
I solved my problem using `Timer` .

Whenever the user changes the `mouse` position or hit a key in `keyboard` on my base Form, the timer restarts.
    and in the `Timer elasped event` I've closed my app.

```
Timer t = new Timer(2*60*1000);
t.Start();
t.elapsed += closeAppFunction;
```

then restarting the timer in Mouse move.

Comment: The linked answer is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the Windows API like this:

```
public sealed class UserActivityMonitor
{
    /// <summary>Determines the time of the last user activity (any mouse activity or key press).</summary>
    /// <returns>The time of the last user activity.</returns>

    public DateTime LastActivity => DateTime.Now - this.InactivityPeriod;

    /// <summary>The amount of time for which the user has been inactive (no mouse activity or key press).</summary>

    public TimeSpan InactivityPeriod
    {
        get
        {
            var lastInputInfo = new LastInputInfo();
            lastInputInfo.CbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(lastInputInfo);
            GetLastInputInfo(ref lastInputInfo);
            uint elapsedMilliseconds = (uint) Environment.TickCount - lastInputInfo.DwTime;
            elapsedMilliseconds = Math.Min(elapsedMilliseconds, int.MaxValue);
            return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(elapsedMilliseconds);
        }
    }

    public async Task WaitForInactivity(TimeSpan inactivityThreshold, TimeSpan checkInterval, CancellationToken cancel)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(checkInterval, cancel);

            if (InactivityPeriod > inactivityThreshold)
                return;
        }
    }

    // ReSharper disable UnaccessedField.Local
    /// <summary>Struct used by Windows API function GetLastInputInfo()</summary>

    struct LastInputInfo
    {
        #pragma warning disable 649
        public int  CbSize;
        public uint DwTime;
        #pragma warning restore 649
    }

    // ReSharper restore UnaccessedField.Local

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool GetLastInputInfo(ref LastInputInfo plii);
}
```

Then you can implement something that closes a form after a certain period of inactivity by doing something like this in the form's overridden `OnLoad()` (this example checks the inactivity every 5 seconds and closes the form if the user was inactive for more than 10 minutes):

```
readonly UserActivityMonitor _monitor = new UserActivityMonitor();

protected override async void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    await _monitor.WaitForInactivity(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), CancellationToken.None);
    this.Close();
}
```